# How to bypass the automatic selection of the display of the form (Customized View) on Android device?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

Is it possible in some way to programmatically bypass automatic selection of the display of the form (Customized View) on Android device?

If I use the automatic selection, Delphi not always correctly determine the resolution and size of Android devices:

```
{$R *.fmx}
{$R *.LgXhdpiTb.fmx ANDROID}
{$R *.SmXhdpiPh.fmx ANDROID}
{$R *.NmXhdpiPh.fmx ANDROID}
{$R *.LgXhdpiPh.fmx ANDROID}
{$R *.XLgXhdpiTb.fmx ANDROID}
```

Let me give a few examples:

GT-I8160P (diagonal size 3.8", resolution 480x800 [320x533]) to be classified as a 5.0" LgXhdpiPh device.

Z220 (diagonal size 4.0", resolution 480x800 [320x533]) to be classified as a 3.5" SmXhdpiPh device.

SM-G360F (diagonal size 4.5", resolution 480x800 [320x533]) to be classified as a 4.0" NmXhdpiPh device.

Someone advise me how to bypass the automatic selection and provide a custom (own) view selection?

Comment: I've created a new Issue on the Embarcadero Quality (see https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-14954)

I'm curious how they will respond.